# Localised Unix shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, localization

Is it possible to get a localised Unix shell, for example, in japanese, arabic or hebrew? Since it should fit on a CD, I want to save space by using Byobu instead of a GUI. But I would like to have an localised command-line interface (at least for logging in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put :

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF8
```

in /etc/default/locale, and

```
sudo locale-gen
```

See /etc/locale.alias for a list of settings.

Comment: Is there a list with the different language codes?

Comment: See my edited post.